# Why don't programs simply use the newest version of C++ Redistributable?

Tags: visual-c++, redistributable

I've read articles explaining that programs that use C++ redistributable will install multiple versions, depending on what they need. But none of the articles I've read have explained *why* it's so important to have different versions. Why can't programs just use the content from the newest version?

The only problem I see is if something gets deprecated. But in that case, I think there should be some handler that can still spit out the desired result. Other than that, the only issue would be that old applications wouldn't follow this "rule" of using newest versions.

So, why isn't it that programs will just use the newest version?

Comment: Once upon a time, things worked the way you describe. [This article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140411-00/?p=1273) provides some color as to why this changed. And now [the old way is coming back](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/)

Comment: Why can't we just use current Ford car parts on all Ford cars? The only problem I see is that years keep getting bigger and technology or functionality changes, but a Ford is always a Ford, right? It shouldn't matter what year Ford it is; clearly parts that fit a Ford made today should also work on a Ford that was manufactured 10 years ago, or 20 years ago. Actually, why shouldn't that GPS system that's in my 2016 Escape work on that 1957 Fairlane in my neighbor's garage? It's all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the VS CRT is version specific. VS 2013 Update 5 version of the CRT will work with a program built by any version of VS 2013, but it doesn't work with VS 2012 or VS 2015. This is because the language and Standard Library makes use of elements of the CRT, and as the compiler changes so does the CRT.

That said, exactly how the servicing is handled has changed over time. Back in VS 2005 / VS 2008, a side-by-side technology known as "Fusion" was employed to try to make it seamless, but it proved to be [quirky](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2008/05/15/vc-runtime-binding/) and to scale poorly. Since VS 2010, "Fusion" is no longer used and programs are expected to either (a) run in the REDIST EXE/MSM to deploy the needed CRT to the `%WINDIR%` or (b) put the DLLs application local with your program's EXE. The first gets serviced by Windows Update, the second does not.

See 
[How to redistribute the Visual C++ Libraries with your application](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2007/10/12/how-to-redistribute-the-visual-c-libraries-with-your-application/) and 
[C-Runtime Deployment: Why choose AppLocal?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/04/18/c-runtime-deployment-why-choosing-applocal/)

For VS 2015 the CRT was refactored to try to make the "compiler-specific" parts of the CRT distinct from the "platform-specific" parts distinct from the "standard functionality" parts. See [The Great C Runtime (CRT) Refactoring](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2014/06/10/the-great-c-runtime-crt-refactoring/) and [Introducing the Universal CRT](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/)

> Note that for Universal Window Platform apps, the Windows Store takes care of deploying the CRT for you.

Answer (score 0):

Due to **DLL Hell** problems, *Side-by-side* assemblies (including native DLLs, not just managed assemblies) were introduced. This resolves DLL hell problem - i.e. various installers overwriting DLLs used by other programs. With SxS, there has to be multiple versions of same DLL, so that no program would break. You cannot have both (same DLL, but SxS assemblies).

Various VC++ runtimes are nothing but SxS assemblies having GUID based DLLs placed in `C:\Windows\WinSxS` - your program is bound to particular version, platform - and it won't break.